# Sending multiple url requests with NSURL Connection

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

I need to send data many times within one view. I have about 6 UISwitches and every time there value gets changed, I need to send (via a POST method) data (a simple NSString) to my php script (http://www.mydomain.com/script/dowork.php)

I have been struggling over the last couple of days in doing this since I have only managed to get this to work with only 1 switch but not when users change multiple switches. If someone can please give me an example of how to do this it would mean a lot.

EDIT

This is how Im doing it now:

```
-(IBAction)switchSelector:(id)sender {
    switch ([sender tag]) {
        case 0:
            if (switchMax.on) {
                //here I Send it to the method that will make the connection
                [self registerWithServer:@"Tokens"]; 

                NSUserDefaults* defaults  = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [defaults setBool: switchMax.on forKey: K_SWITCH_KEY];
                [defaults synchronize];
            } else {
                //other stuff
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to properly format your code - it is a mess as it stands right now.

Answer (score 0):

How did you manage to do it with one switch? Could you post the code as well?
For multiple switches just hook up your method with the valueChanged in interface builder. Inside that method check which switch is on - `if ([mySwitch1 isOn])`, edit your `NSString` and send it.

Comment: the problem is not with the switches or identifying which switch has been changed... The problem is sending data multiple times with NSURLConnection. I do not know how to do that.... Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand it now. Just do `[self registerWithServer:@"new str"]`for other switches.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how you would send data multiple times over nsurl connection with a "Post". That's the real issue. The switches are fine

Comment: [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566516/simple-http-post-example-in-xcode) or [link2](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=689884). Just do it multiple times. Im sure there are even more results if you google just a little.

Comment: Thanks Majester but I have implemented something similar as link1. It's not working for me when I need to do this multiple times in the same view one after the other

Answer (score 0):

Just some thoughts, but do you really need to send the changes to your server immediately? Assuming that these switches are used in some settings panel, you could save the settings once the user is done with the panel and send it to your server, e.g. when they press the Done button or exit from this view. This way, you only send the request once without having to be burdened with sending it multiple times.

Keep in mind that the user is on a mobile device and you should try to keep data usage as low as possible.