# Create a JsonString in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am new in iOS. I created a `JSON NSDictionary` like this:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"User", @"Password", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Ali", @"2020", nil];
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
```

And then I could convert it to `NSString` via two mechanisms:

1)

```
NSError *error; 
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:0 error:&error];

NSString *jsonString = nil;
if (! jsonData) {
     NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
} else {
     jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

2)

```
NSString *jsonString = [jsonDictionary JSONRepresentation];
```

In the second way I get this `warning` :

```
Instance method '-JSONRepresentation' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

But when I run the project, both of the mechanisms works fine:

```
NSLog(@"Val of json parse obj is %@",jsonString);
```

Do you know how can I remove the warning in the second way?

**My main goal is `POST` this json String to an external database using RESTful Web Service.
Basically which way is better considering my main goal?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `NSJSONSerialization` as it is faster and comes directly with iOS SDK as long as your "target audience" is iOS5+

To POST the data to your web service you need the create a request along these lines...

```
NSDictionary * postDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value1", @"value2", nil]
                                                                  forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"key1", @"key2", nil]];

NSError * error = nil;
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDictionary options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your_webservice_post_url"]];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:jsonData];

NSURLConnection * myConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

Please read up on [NSURLConnectionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/)  protocol.

Comment: I used the code but nothing posted to my external database. I tried [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456966/how-to-send-json-data-in-the-http-request-using-nsurlrequest) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566516/simple-http-post-example-in-xcode?rq=1) but they didn't work also. can you guess what is the problem? I can successfully connect the database and GET but not POST

Comment: Did you execute some type of connection with the above request? [You should never use synchronous connections unless having some good reason but for this purpose] - `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error: &error];`

Comment: I updated the answer to show the NSURLConnection in it. There are better ways of implementing such connection but that is out of scope of this question.

Comment: That was what I exactly done by the second link. But you are right I may ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 4):

**For iOS 5.0 >** :

Use [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html) like this :

```
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *resultAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"jsonData as string:\n%@ Error:%@", resultAsString,error);
```

**For < iOS 5** :

Use [json-framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) a third party library that uses category for `NSDictionary` to provide json string :

```
 NSString *jsonString = [dictionary JSONRepresentation];

 //with options
 NSString *jsonString = [dictionary JSONStringWithOptions:JKSerializeOptionNone error:nil]
```

Comment: That's what I did exactly regarding `JSONRepresentation`. Take a look at my question. Which one is better considering my case?

Comment: And also the `warning` I got on `JSONRepresentation`

Comment: use NSJSONSerialization its best

Comment: SBJSON and JSONKit is thirdparty library . So to use them u need to add them in your project. NSJSONSerialization is in built apple's library

Comment: Yes, I know that. what about my case (talk to a **Web Service**)? And please let me about your reason.

Comment: I appreciate for your suggestion. I think you are right about `NSJSONSerialization` @Peter described it in a better way. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you... [Convert NSDictionary to JSON with SBJson](http://www.lifeofatechdude.com/2011/06/convert-nsdictionary-to-json.html)

Comment: It is another mechanism to convert the `Dictionary` to `String`. OK but which one is better considering my main goal which is talk to a `Web Service`? :)

Comment: We can use `NSJSONSerialization` instead of `SBJson`. Which one is better in my case?

Answer (score 0):

use this way i hope it will help you

```
 NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"User", @"Password", nil];
 NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Ali", @"2020", nil];
 NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

 NSError *error = nil;
 // NSError *error; 
 NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:0 error:&error];


 id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

 NSLog(@"\n\n\n id for json==%@ \n\n\n\n\n",result);
```

Comment: Please take a look at the end of my question. What is the use of this way considering my main goal?

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON DEFAULT METHOD......

+(NSDictionary *)stringWithUrl:(NSURL *)url postData:(NSData *)postData httpMethod:(NSString *)method { 

NSDictionary *returnResponse=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];

@try {
 NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:180]; [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:method];

if(postData != nil)
{
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
}

[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[urlRequest setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

NSData *urlData;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                returningResponse:&response
                                            error:&error];
returnResponse = [NSJSONSerialization
                  JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                  options:kNilOptions
                  error:&error];
} @catch (NSException *exception) { returnResponse=nil; } @finally { return returnResponse; } }

Return Method :

+(NSDictionary )methodName:(NSString)string { 
NSDictionary *returnResponse; NSData *postData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[string UTF8String] length:[string length]]; NSString *urlString = @"https//:..url...."; returnResponse=[self stringWithUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] postData:postData httpMethod:@"POST"];
return returnResponse; 
}
```

Comment: You posted this answer on more than one question. Please do not do that. Each question should be answered on its own terms; if the answers are the same, then one of the questions should be marked as a duplicate of the other. You will be able to vote to do this when you have enough reputation.