# Xcode Map Callout: 5 Star Rating widget

Tags: xcode

For the callouts on a map pin annotations I have always wanted to add in '5 Star rating' widget that can update in real time without me having to dig in the code and add in the data that people have added. I understand that you can use php with Xcode if you use the specific plug-ins. Is this 5 Star Widget possible?

If it is, would I have to do anything else besides input the code for the widget on each call out? would I have to manage a php database?

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 0):

I have come across '5 Star Rating Widget' as well, and what I have done is this:

1) Created 10 images. - First one has 5 white stars meaning the rating is 0. The second image has the first star on the left half red and the rest are white, indicating rating of 0.5. The third image has the first star on the left all red and the rest are white, indicating a rating of 1.0 out of 5. and so on.

2) Saved these 10 images onto Xcode,. as star20.png for rating of 2.0, star15.png for rating of 1.5 and so on. You'll see later on why I named these in this way.

3) Created a call from Xcode to PHP using query such as device=ios&locationID=123456 or whatever the locationID is for that map pin is. (reference: [Simple http post example in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566516/simple-http-post-example-in-objective-c))

4) php processes the location ID and gathers the rating for that place through MySQL database, and analyse it to a discrete value such as 00,05,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45 or 50. So if the rating is 4.21, then it's between 3.75 and 4.25 so the rating I would show is 4.0 and I multiplied it by 10 because it's easier on the eye. This is done through PHP.

5) Xcode obtains the PHP output through NSURLConnection and outputs the image.
PHP gets the rating for example 35. Append 35 to @"star" and then append ".png" to create an image name for that location. Then use UIImageView to output the rating image as 5 stars.

This was a brief overview but I hope this helps.