# Sending post request IOS 7

Tags: ios, http, post

Okay I have been trying to adapt to objective C and it has been a roller coaster for me, anyways I am just trying to send a simple post request to a server, however it doesn't look as simple as it was for android. Currently I have the following method:

```
-(void)postMethod
{

    [self.connection cancel];

    //initialize new mutable data
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    self.receivedData = data;

    //initialize url that is going to be fetched.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blank.com/register.php"];

    //initialize a request from url
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]];

    //set http method
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    //initialize a post data
    NSString *postData = @"username=postTest&displayname=testingPoster&password=postest&passwordc=postest&email=posttesting%40posttest.com&bio=I+am+tesring+the+post+test&skills=I+am+a+hacka&interests=hacing+and+cracking&skills_needed=some+php+skills&company=Post+testing+the+script&dob=naaaaaa&occupation=Qoekkk";
    //Here you can give your parameters value

    //set request content type we MUST set this value.

    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    //set post data of request
    [request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //initialize a connection from request
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    self.connection = connection;


    //start the connection
    [connection start];
}
```

and I have a button to call the function:

```
- (IBAction)register:(id)sender {

    [self postMethod];


}
```

I did make sure I included the NSURLConnectionDataDelegate in my header file, however when I try to send the request when I click the button, it doesn't go through and it just stops the program, it doesn't any error. Any suggestions, I have been searching all over the net just to learn how to send a post request, I don't think it should be very difficult.

And just incase it matters, I am using the latest iphone sdk for ios 7.

Comment: Take a look at [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). Simplifies this quite a bit ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple http post example in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566516/simple-http-post-example-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 3):

Note that for iOS 7 [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) is the recommended way to go. NSURLConnection will probably be deprecated in future releases. You can make your POST request using either of the three types of [URL session tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTask_class/Reference/Reference.html). [NSURLSessionDataTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDataTask_class/Reference/Reference.html) is pretty much equivalent to NSURLConnection. [NSURLSessionUploadTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionUploadTask_class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSURLSessionDownloadTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDownloadTask_class/Reference/Reference.html) (which writes received data to the disk) can be used in a background session and continue (in another process) even if your application gets suspended or crashes. More can be read in [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html).

Answer (score 1):

[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) is tried and tested. - check out the example below which also uses basic authentication:

```
- (void)postToAPI   {

    NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourdomain.com/api/operation"];

    AFHTTPClient* httpClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:postURL];
    httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    [httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];

    // Set up authentication - Get username from keychain
    KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"bnmcred" accessGroup:nil];
    NSString *password = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
    NSString *username = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];

    [httpClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:username password:password];

    // Create Post Dictionary
    NSMutableDictionary* postRequestDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    postRequestDictionary[@"your_post_item_1"] = @"Hello";
    postRequestDictionary[@"your_post_item_2"] = @"World";

    // Create Request
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:nil parameters:postRequestDictionary];

    self.httpOperation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Success");

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Failure with error:%@", error);
    }];

    [self.httpOperation start];
}
```