# How to make HTTP-POST in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, http-post

I want to send a HTTP-POST message to a server. I have searched on the internet and there where only very old posts. THis was the best one: [Simple http post example in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566516/simple-http-post-example-in-objective-c)

Does this still works? or are there new ways to make an HTTP-POST message?

Answer (score 0):

You should use AFNetworking lib: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

[ASIHTTP Request](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request) is undoubtedly a great way for a HTTP-POST communication. This is probably the easiest to use also...

Answer (score 0):

Here's [another tutorial](http://www.creativepulse.gr/en/blog/2014/restful-api-requests-using-objective-c-works-on-ios-and-mac) for making GET, simple POST and multipart POST requests.

Look up "URL encoded HTTP POST requests" :)