# Xcode insert into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c

I'm currently using a method to retrieve data with php and a $_GET[''], but i need to insert data now, but there will be quite a few things to be added with a single submission.

for example;

- Question (text)
- QuestionA (text)
- QuestionB (text)
- QuestionC (text)
- QuestionD (text)
- Correct (varchar)
- Catagory (varchar)
- difficulty (int)

So the question itself could be a whopping 500char or something, and to use a $_GET method then will I not face difficulty when trying to use certain characters or special characters that a user could submit?

If the data with url method in xcode is the only way then I get I have no choice, but can anyone give me advice on how to make this process more efficient?

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"***.php?question=%@&qa=%@&qb=%@&qc=%@&qd=%@&ca=%@&dif=%i&cat=%@", self.question, self.qA, self.qB, self.qC, self.qD, self.correctAns, self.dif, self.catagory];
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Comment: Why don't you use `$_POST`?

Comment: How can I $_POST from xcode / iOS app ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566516/simple-http-post-example-in-objective-c

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks like a much simpler way than what I was attempting.