# What's the equivalent of this curl request in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, curl

I have the following curl command:

```
curl -X POST \
 -H "X-dadadadad: APITokenInt" \
 -F "log=@logfile.log" \
 apilink.com
```

I'd like to perform a similar action in Objective-C code, but don't know how. What is the equivalent of the above in Objective-C?

Comment: This POST request example should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3566539/4657588

Comment: @dan A little confused what to put for parameters and headers and such.

Comment: @BradLarson Why was this reopened? Please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265825/code-translation-tagging

Comment: @rmaddy - Because I thought it was broader in impact that your typical "translate this for me" request. With a little work, I thought it could be a decent question and it has received a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create the request.
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/appID/crashes/upload"]];

// Specify that it will be a POST request
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

// This is how we set header fields
[request setValue:@"APITokenInt" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-HockeyAppToken"];

// Convert your data and set your request's HTTPBody property
NSString *stringData = @"some data";
NSData *requestBodyData = [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;

// Create url connection and fire request
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

The parameters you mention can just be set in the URL or in the body of the POST request.

**Update - Forms**

If you want to send a POST request and set the type to a form, then set the header of the request like so:

```
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

**Update 2 - Multiple headers**

In your case you are going to need to set multiple headers, which can be done. You can do this by using the `addValue` method instead of the `setValue` method like so:

```
[request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"APITokenInt" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-HockeyAppToken"];
```

Comment: Thank you. What about if what I am posting is a form file?

Comment: @user3792038 I updated my answer, but you basically need to state that in the header of the request.

Comment: And then what about the file itself?

Comment: and do I still use the two headers or just one?

Comment: @user3792038 Yes in your case you will need to use multiple headers which can be done. I updated my answer for this.

Comment: @user3792038 The file itself (as in data?) should be part of the body of the request. You can either pass it as data via ```NSData``` or you can convert it to a string and add it to the body that way.

Comment: For some reason my request isn't firiing.